# Mono 5.20.1.19 crash and runtime and class libraries out of sync warnings

Tags: linux, mono, com-interop

Built Mono 5.20.1.19 master on Linux from GitHub. "make check" showed every unit testing passed. Then I used this mono to build my project. But when I run unit testings of my project, mono crashed in couple cases. These cases are related to cominterop and BSTR marshaling. I noticed a warning states:
Your mono runtime and class libraries are out of sync.
The out of sync library is: MyInterop.dll

When you update one from git you need to update, compile and install
the other too. Do not report this as a bug unless you're sure you have updated correctly: you probably have a broken mono install.
If you see other errors or faults after this message they are probably related and you need to fix your mono install first.

Apparently every library of my project was build with mono 5.20.1.19. If you use mono 4.8, there is no such out of sync issue and the unit testings are good. Why there is such warning and is it to the crash of mono?

Comment: Thanks for the response.
C# code:

MySetRegistryLoadConfiguration(MyRegistryLoadConfig.My_RegistryLoadConfig_Txt);
ListCpp<string> list = new ListCpp<string>();
list.Add("a");
stack trace when mono crashed at list.Add("a") 
(gdb) mono_backtrace 15
#9  0x00007f636cbf18ee in MyNamespace::CoTaskMemFree(void*) const () 
#10 0x00007f636cbf1d77 in MyNamespace::ComProxyPOSIX::SysFreeString(wchar_t*) const ()

#11 0x00007f636cbef934 in MyNamespace::SysFreeString(wchar_t*) () 
#12 0x00007f636cc444bd in MyNamespace::ans_mono_free_bstr_fcn(wchar_t*) () mylibrary.so

Comment: Managed Stacktrace:

          at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
          at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal:FreeBSTR <0x000bd>
          at System.Variant:Clear <0x00030>
          at MyNamespace._VariantCollClass:Add <0x0011a>
          at MyNamespace._VariantCollClass:Add <0x00047>
          at MyNamespace._VariantCollClass:Add <0x00037>
          at MyNamespace.Interop.ListCpp`1:Add <0x0003b>
          at TestVariantColl:Main <0x0008b>

Comment: Sorry for the messy. C++ Com code corresponding to ListCpp was not posted. My company has been using mono in our commercial software for many years. We patched official mono before it was used in our products. So FreeBSTR and CoTaskMem stuff call our routines.